# Maven Doesnot Overwrite files in target folder

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am using maven for build, downloading war from artifactory and in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ folder customized one of the file but in target//WEB_INF/ the file is not overwriting with the customized file in the final war.
I used true in maven resources plugin.
EG:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-app</id>
                    <!-- <phase>process-resources</phase> -->
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                      <outputDirectory>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB_INF</directory>
                                <includes>
                                <include>app.xml</include></includes>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: You know about https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html ?

Answer (score 1):

First run `mvn clean`  which will remove target, and then run `mvn install` should create artifact with latest changes.

if `mvn clean` is not removing target folder, check if there are any access issues

Comment: I am using command as - clean install -X, but still not overwriting